# Running snakemake with several cores

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I am trying to run a Snakefile using snakemake, which works fine when I go into the right directory and type

```
conda create --name durp python=3.5
snakemake
```

However, if I now use the `-j` switch to use more than 1 core, I get an error

```
snakemake -j 8
ERROR: Running in parallel is not supported on Python 2
```

I am specifying `python3.5` when I create a conda environment though…I am not sure why I get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you activate the env? Is snakemake installed in that env?

Comment: Yes, I activated the environment, then installed snakemake using conda `conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake`